# Scaling UIView using transform after animating frame change causes UIView to jump back to original frame before scaling

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewanimation, cgaffinetransform

I'm trying to scale a UIView (with animation) after I move it (with animation). The problem is, when the scaling animation begins, it jumps back to the original position. Why?

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:t delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
    // Drop the ball

    CGRect frame = coinView.frame;
    frame.origin.y += d;

    coinView.frame = frame;

    coinView.shouldSparkle = NO;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        // Initial scale up for ball "poof"

        coinView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(coinView.transform, 1.5, 1.5);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
            coinView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(coinView.transform, 0.000001, 0.000001);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [coinView removeFromSuperview];
        }];
    }];
}];
```

EDIT: This is how I generated my d:

```
static CGFloat groundPositionY = 325;

CGRect convertedFrame = [coinView.superview convertRect:coinView.frame toView:self.view];

CGFloat d = groundPositionY - CGRectGetMaxY(convertedFrame);
```

EDIT2: Okay, so I changed the second UIView animation to the following and I discovered that the jump (and the scale *down*) happens before the second animation occurs, i.e. when animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion: is called.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:5 delay:3 options:0 animations:^{
    coinView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(coinView.transform, 1.5, 1.5);
} completion:nil];
```

Comment: have you tried removing the second and third animations and check whether the view keeps its position? are you doing anything to the view outside of this block of code (I mean, after it)?

Comment: Yup, I have and it does. Nope, I'm not touching these views (or any views for that matter) after this block of code.

Comment: If I do `coinView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, d);` instead of frame change, then it does something weird too (it shifts it by -d in the y direction and then animates it going positive in the y direction until it reaches the original position)

Comment: Do you think it matters that the coinView's layer contents is set to a CGImage? EDIT: I changed it to a UIImageView subview and nothing changed.

Comment: The scaling is backwards too (it scales down by -1.5 and then animates it back to normal). Why??

Comment: `coinView.transform` before second animation block is `CGAffineTransformIdentity`.

Comment: Is autolayout enabled in your xib or storyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem...

The coinView is a subview of a child view controller's view. The problem comes from the fact that I overrode that child view controller's `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method to lay out all the `coinView`'s, so whenever that method was called, the coin view would move back to its original position and size intended by the child view controller.

Thanks for all of your help, repoguy and sergio!!

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code and it works fine for me. How do you generate your d? and on which block exactly it goes back?

Comment: Actually I'm not sure if it goes back to the original position, but it definitely jumps somewhere else. See my edit for question about d. It jumps when the second animation block starts.

Comment: I'm using the same code as you do and cannot replicate the error that you get. I'm using a button but it doesn't matter for this as it is still UIView and it goes slowly down then scale up and scale down. Are you sure you don't move your view somewhere from outside the animation block? As the view is instantly in the position specified by the last animation it just takes time for the end user to see the animation.

Comment: Very sure. Also, I just fixed a mistake `UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn` should be `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn`...but that still doesn't fix it. =(

Comment: then I don't know what's wrong. Lastly I would check the same animation with different view like button or label or even image view created just before the animation

Comment: then your old view doesn't work as you expect, how do you create it? apply one function at the time to the new view and look what's happening